# Исчезающая кнопка при скролле

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, прокрутка

Цель, сделать кнопку, которая будет появляться при скролле страницы, и вести к блоку в низу. Когда мы доедем до блока кнопка должна исчезнуть.

Решил сделать на основе `scrollToTop`. Первая часть действий работает, кнопка появляется, при клике мы едем к блокам, а как сделать чтобы она потом исчезла.

Вот `js` скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1300) {
            $('#scroller2').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#scroller2').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    $('#scroller2').click(function () {
        $('#speak').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#scroller2').click(function () {
    $('#speak').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100); 
    $(this).fadeOut();
    return false;
});
```

Если нужно именно после того как спустились вниз, то действие $(this).fadeOut(); запустите через некоторое время ( т.е. то время, которое вы задаёте для анимации).

Comment: Если ставить этот прием то кнопка тухнет при нажатии на нее когда страница статична. И когда нажимаем на нее, получается она тухнет и опять появляется, ведь происходит скролл к диву

Comment: setTimeout(function() { $(this).fadeOut(); }, timeAnimation); В Вашем случае timeAnimation = 100;

Comment: Что-то ей мешает. Когда жмем на кнопку и едем к диву, она тухнет, но как подъезжаем, появляется. Крутил timeAnimation не помогло

Comment: можете выложить пример на jsfiddle?

Comment: Вот пример, справа внизу темный див. http://rabota.aubakirovalexandr.com/